# Output different value after function call?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I'm confusing about the different **sizeof()** return value after function **check()** calls. And **buf** exactly the same as **buffer** based on the **printf()** for each char. Any reply is awesome! Thx.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void check(char *buf)
{

    printf("%d \n", sizeof(buf)); // **output 8**

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char buffer[] = "\x64\x49\x00\x55\x33\x33\x33\x64\x49\x00\x00\x00\x55\x33\x33\x33\x64\x49\x00\x00\x00\x55\x33\x33\x64\x49\x00\x00\x00\x55\x33\x33";
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(buffer)); // **output 33**
    check(buffer);

}
```

Comment: size of pointer vs size of an array?

Answer (score 1):

In function `check` buffer is a pointer to the `char` and its size is 8

In the `main` furnctions buffers is the 33 elements char array and its size is 33

To get the length of the C string use `strlen` function.

Generally there is no way of getting the size of the array referenced by the pointer. You need to pass the size as a anothother parameter.

In your example:

```
void check(char *buf, size_t size)
{

    printf("%zu \n", size);

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char buffer[] = "\x64\x49\x00\x55\x33\x33\x33\x64\x49\x00\x00\x00\x55\x33\x33\x33\x64\x49\x00\x00\x00\x55\x33\x33\x64\x49\x00\x00\x00\x55\x33\x33";
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(buffer)); // **output 33**
    check(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

}
```

Comment: thx!233 then can I get the size of char array in function check?